# How to add a trigger that run after all the Update are done

Tags: database, oracle, triggers

I have this trigger and would like to do one more update but only after all update are done not to be row level

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER comp_bu_cat
  FOR UPDATE ON Cats COMPOUND TRIGGER
  tiger_percentage NUMBER;
  tiger_touched NUMBER := 0;
  nice_difference NUMBER := 1;
  increase NUMBER;
  BEFORE STATEMENT IS 
  BEGIN
    SELECT NVL(mice_ration, 0)  INTO tiger_percentage FROM Cats WHERE nickname='TIGER';
    SELECT Max(NVL(mice_ration, 0))  INTO increase FROM Cats WHERE function='NICE' AND gender='W';
    
  END BEFORE STATEMENT;

BEFORE EACH ROW IS
BEGIN
    IF (:NEW.mice_ration  - :OLD.mice_ration) <  (tiger_percentage * 0.1) AND :OLD.gender = 'W' AND :OLD.function = 'NICE'
    THEN :NEW.mice_ration := :OLD.mice_ration + (tiger_percentage * 0.1);
         :NEW.mice_extra := :OLD.mice_extra + 5;
     -- decrease the value of the tiger by 10 %  and mice extra by five
         nice_difference := nice_difference * 0; 
    ELSIF (:NEW.mice_ration  - :OLD.mice_ration) > (tiger_percentage * 0.1) AND :OLD.gender = 'W' AND :OLD.function = 'NICE'
    THEN -- increase the mice his ration by 
        nice_difference := nice_difference + 1 ;    
    END IF;
 END BEFORE EACH ROW;  
 END comp_bu_cat;
```

I would like to add this

```
IF tiger_touched = 0 AND nice_difference = 0 AND :OLD.function = 'BOSS'
    THEN :NEW.mice_ration := :OLD.mice_ration - (tiger_percentage * 0.1);
        tiger_touched := 1;
    ELSIF  tiger_touched = 0 AND nice_difference > 0 AND :OLD.function = 'BOSS'
    THEN :NEW.mice_extra := :OLD.mice_extra + 5;
        :NEW.mice_ration := :OLD.mice_ration + 0;
        tiger_touched := 1;
 END IF;
```

but should be triggered after the whole update is done. when adding it inside the above compound trigger I get an infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

Well, normally you'd use the AFTER STATEMENT trigger point in your compound trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER comp_bu_cat
  FOR UPDATE ON Cats COMPOUND TRIGGER
  tiger_percentage NUMBER;
  tiger_touched NUMBER := 0;
  nice_difference NUMBER := 1;
  increase NUMBER;

  BEFORE STATEMENT IS 
  BEGIN
    SELECT NVL(mice_ration, 0)
      INTO tiger_percentage
      FROM Cats
      WHERE nickname='TIGER';

    SELECT Max(NVL(mice_ration, 0))
      INTO increase
      FROM Cats
      WHERE function='NICE' AND
            gender='W';
  END BEFORE STATEMENT;

  BEFORE EACH ROW IS
    BEGIN
      IF (:NEW.mice_ration  - :OLD.mice_ration) < (tiger_percentage * 0.1) AND
         :OLD.gender = 'W' AND
         :OLD.function = 'NICE'
      THEN
        :NEW.mice_ration := :OLD.mice_ration + (tiger_percentage * 0.1);
        :NEW.mice_extra := :OLD.mice_extra + 5;
        -- decrease the value of the tiger by 10 %  and mice extra by five
        nice_difference := nice_difference * 0; 
      ELSIF (:NEW.mice_ration  - :OLD.mice_ration) > (tiger_percentage * 0.1) AND
            :OLD.gender = 'W' AND
            :OLD.function = 'NICE'
      THEN  -- increase the mice his ration by 
        nice_difference := nice_difference + 1 ;    
      END IF;
  END BEFORE EACH ROW;  

  AFTER STATEMENT IS
  BEGIN
    IF tiger_touched = 0 AND
       nice_difference = 0 AND
       :OLD.function = 'BOSS'
    THEN
      :NEW.mice_ration := :OLD.mice_ration - (tiger_percentage * 0.1);
      tiger_touched := 1;
    ELSIF tiger_touched = 0 AND
          nice_difference > 0 AND
          :OLD.function = 'BOSS'
    THEN :NEW.mice_extra := :OLD.mice_extra + 5;
      :NEW.mice_ration := :OLD.mice_ration + 0;
      tiger_touched := 1;
    END IF;
  END;
END comp_bu_cat;
```

Except - this won't really work because you don't have access to the `:NEW` and `:OLD` pseudo-rows since the BEFORE STATEMENT and AFTER STATEMENT trigger points are only invoked once, no matter how many rows are updated and thus they have no row-related data available.

I suggest that when processing the rows in your `BEFORE EACH ROW` that you keep track of the primary key of the row you want to change in your AFTER STATEMENT trigger point and then perform your desired update there.

Comment: the after statement also an update which then leads to and infinite loop too, will that update in the after statement not trigger again my compound statement ? @Bob Jarvis - Reinstate Monica